# Using prependTo element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a the following Hmtl:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="data-confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="data-confirmation-modal-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="data-confirmation-modal-label">Titile</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Example</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="" type="button" class="btn-confirm">Conform</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn-cancel" autofocus="" data-dismiss="modal">Avbryt</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a form element and put modal content inside form element in javascipt:

```
$form = $("<form></form>"); 
$form.prependTo($('.modal-content'));
```

When I use the above code I the modal is empty. Would appreciate some help.
I want html to be as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="data-confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="data-confirmation-modal-label">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
       <form>
              <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="data-confirmation-modal-label">Titile</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Example</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="" type="button" class="btn-confirm">Conform</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-cancel" autofocus="" data-dismiss="modal">Avbryt</button>
              </div>
      </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) is not used for wrapping. It is used to add/transfer another element at the beginning of the target element

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".modal-content").children().wrapAll("<form></form>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade in" id="data-confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="data-confirmation-modal-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="data-confirmation-modal-label">Titile</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Example</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="" type="button" class="btn-confirm">Conform</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn-cancel" autofocus="" data-dismiss="modal">Avbryt</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

1. Use `.wrapAll()` to wrap the all content

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap .modal-content with a form using jquery wrap http://api.jquery.com/wrap/
or you can rewrite the entire html but with the form,like

```
$('.modal-content').html('<form>'+$('.modal-content').html()+'</form>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
$(".modal-content").wrap("<form></form>").
```